# How to get checkout form data for logged in and guest customers in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I need to get checkout form data before placing order, but I am only getting  default shipping address below is the code snippet I tried:

> \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session

```
$customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();  
$customerInfo = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
$customerAddress = $customerInfo->getDefaultShippiingAddress();
```

`getshipiingAddress()` method returning null

I want to get form data for logged in and guest customer both.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this and posting here to help otheres:

```
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

            $billingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($billingAddress->getData()); echo '</pre>';

            $shippingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($shippingAddress->getData()); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get cart data using checkout session class.

Use this code in your class:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
)
{
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

}
```

And following code to get quote data.

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote(); // get quote data
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress(); //get shipping address
```